# dificultad con Handlebars.registerHelper en handlebars

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, express, handlebars.js

tengo un proyecto en nodejs, y estoy utilizando handlebars, y express y otras librerias. Es un pryecto personal para mejorar mi inglés, la gracia es registrar en base de datos las palabras que me sé y que el sistema me las valla lanzando al azar(en español) y yo las tenga que traducir(al inglés), esto ya lo hice sin node, pero ahora estoy pasandolo a nodejs :D

### Objetivo:

El objetivo de lo que quiero hacer es que según la ruta en la que me encuentre puedan variar los scripts, me explico, estoy realizando una app para mi, para practicar inglés, la cosa es que cuando esté en la ruta de words(practicar palabras :D), que me salga el script correspondiente a esa ruta, y si me paso a la ruta de phrases por ejemplo, pues que ya no salga el script de words, sino el de phrases y asi...

### Solucion (la cual no me ha servido :c )

mediante bloques de helpers, indicarle al archivo main de mis vistas (el que va a aparecer en todas las vistas), en que ruta me encuentro, de esa manera con condicionales puedo indicarle a la vista main de mi handlebars que script debe de utilizar :D

### Problema

Me he enredado con esto, trato de implementar el siguiente bloque:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('pathWords', (opts) => {
    return location.pathname == '/practices/words' ? opts.fn(this) : opts.inverse(this);
});
```

Según lo que investigué, asi debería quedar (creo, nisiquiera estoy seguro de si es asi ajsjajsa), también no encontre ningún lugar en donde me indiquen en que parte colocarlo, ya lo coloqué en el index de mi proyecto y en el archivo de helpers de mi handlebars, y nada :(, entonces porfavor si me pueden decir como se hace bien lo de los bloques o en su defecto me den otra solucion mas viable para cambiar dinamicamente los scripts dependiendo en que ruta me encuentre :D.

Anexo codigo de la configuracion de mi handlebars:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('.hbs', exHbs({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    layoutsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'layouts'),
    partialsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'partials'),
    extname: '.hbs',
    helpers: require('./lib/handlebars')
}));
```

Rutas:

```
//Routes
app.use(require('./routes/home'));
app.use(require('./routes/statistics'));
app.use('/practices', require('./routes/practices'));
```

Mi archivo main.hbs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="" id="styles">
    <title>Learn English</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

    {{> nav}}

    {{{body}}}
    
</body>
{{#pathWords}}
<script src="/js/words.js" id="javascript"></script>
{{/pathWords}}
<script src="/js/changeStyles.js"></script>
</html>
```

Y por si acaso anexo foto del orden o jeraquia de mis archivos en el proyecto :D

[image: imagen 1 de mi proyecto con el cual tengo problemas]

[image: imagen 2 de mi proyecto con el cual tengo problemas]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para todos los interesados ya encontre la respuesta, al parecer estaba viendo la documentacion equivocada JAJAJAJ, en la verdadera documentacion encontré que así se deben de colocar los helpers:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('home', {
        helpers: {
            miHelper: function () { return 'this is my helper :D'; }
        }
    });
});
```

Pero en la misma documentacion encontré una mejor manera de variar los scripts según la ubicacion, la cual sería mandandole un objeto con una variable asi:

```
router.get('/words', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('practices/words', {showWords:true});
});

router.get('/phrases', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('practices/phrases', {showPhrases:true});
});
```

y en el main de mi handlebars quedaría así:

```
{{#if showWords}}
<script src="/js/words.js"></script>
{{/if}}

{{#if showPhrases}}
<script src="/js/phrases.js"></script>
{{/if}}
```

Y de esa manera dependiendo en que ruta me encuentre muestro ciertos scripts...
Por cierto me estaba guiando de la documentacion oficial de handlebars, pero me tenia que guiar era de la documentacion de express-handlebars npm, la cual es esta: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars

Bueno, espero les sirva :D